# ReadFile code using Win32 API to read from serial port very slow

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port, readfile

I'm trying to read 2048 samples from an nRF52832 chip via COM port on my PC. I have connected the UART pins from the nRF-chip to the computer using a UART-to-USB cable. I have been able to `printf` and `NRF_LOG_INFO` from it previously at a baud rate of 921600. Now that I want to do something with the data, in real time, I need to read it myself. But when I run the attached code (see below), it takes over 15 seconds to read these samples, that should have been read in about 1 second.

Any ideas on how to make this code run faster?

*(the real-time aspect will be added later, for now my goal is to get the program to read fast enough)*

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SUCCESS 0
#define BUF_SIZE 2048


char* hComm_init_error_modes[7] = {"",             //NOT INTENDED FOR USE
                                   "",             //NOT INTENDED FOR USE
                                  "ERROR OPENING SERIAL PORT\n",
                                  "ERROR RETRIEVING COMM STATE\n",
                                  "ERROR CONFIGURING COMM STATE\n",
                                  "ERROR RETRIEVING COMM TIMEOUTS\n",
                                  "ERROR CONFIGURING COMM TIMEOUTS\n",};



HANDLE hComm;

uint8_t m_buf[BUF_SIZE];
uint8_t single_val_buf[1];
//int m_buf_full = 0;

int hComm_init(char* port){

    hComm = CreateFileA(port,                           //PORT NAME
                        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,   //READ/WRITE
                        0,                              //NO SHARING
                        NULL,                           //NO SECURITY
                        OPEN_EXISTING,                  //OPEN EXISTING PORT ONLY
                        0,                              //NON OVERLAPPED I/O
                        NULL);                          //NULL FOR COMM DEVICES


    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        return 2;
    }

    DCB commStateConfig;

    if (!GetCommState(hComm, &commStateConfig)){
        return 3;
    }

    commStateConfig.BaudRate = 921600;
    commStateConfig.ByteSize = 8;

    if (!SetCommState(hComm, &commStateConfig)){
        return 4;
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS comm_timeouts;

    if (!GetCommTimeouts(hComm, &comm_timeouts)){
        return 5;
    }

    comm_timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
    comm_timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    comm_timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
    comm_timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    comm_timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;

    if (!SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &comm_timeouts)){
        return 6;
    }

    return 0;
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (argc != 2){
        printf("\nWrong number of inputs! Please provide the com port number and nothing else.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char portname[11+strlen(argv[1])];
    strcpy(portname, "\\\\.\\COM");
    strcat(portname, argv[1]);

    int err = hComm_init(portname);

    if (err != SUCCESS){
        printf("%s", hComm_init_error_modes[err]);
        goto RUNTIME_ERROR;
    }

    printf("OPENED AND CONFIGURED SERIAL PORT SUCCESSFULLY\n");


    if (!SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR)){
        printf("SetCommMask failed with error code: %ld\n", GetLastError());
        goto RUNTIME_ERROR;
    }

    DWORD dwEvtMask;
    DWORD read;
    int readcount = 0;


    while (1){
        read = 0;
        dwEvtMask = 0;

        if(kbhit()) //Check for key press
        {
            if(27 == getch()) // ESC pressed
            {
                printf("Key ESC pressed, exiting...\n");
                goto CLEAN_EXIT;
            }
        }


        if (WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwEvtMask, NULL)) 
        {   

            if (dwEvtMask & EV_ERR) 
            {
                printf("Wait failed with error %ld.\n", GetLastError());
                goto RUNTIME_ERROR;
            }


            if (dwEvtMask & EV_RXCHAR) 
            {   
                if(!ReadFile(hComm, single_val_buf, 1, &read, NULL)){
                    printf("\n\nERROR when reading\n\n");
                }
                m_buf[readcount] = *single_val_buf;
                readcount++;
            }

            if (readcount == BUF_SIZE){
                double diff_ms = (clock()-start) * 1000. / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                print_m_buf(); //for testing only, remove later
                printf("Time spent reading: %f ms\n", diff_ms);
                goto CLEAN_EXIT;
            }
        } else {
            DWORD dwRet = GetLastError();
            if( ERROR_IO_PENDING == dwRet)
            {
                printf("I/O is pending...\n");

                // To do.
            }
            else 
                printf("Wait failed with error %ld.\n", GetLastError());
        }
    }


CLEAN_EXIT:
    CloseHandle(hComm);
    return 0;

RUNTIME_ERROR:
    printf("Runtime error, program exited.\n");
    CloseHandle(hComm);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You are making OS calls for every byte read (one byte at a time) and to check for key input. That's a lot of dead weight. Can you read as many characters as are waiting, and check for key input every, say, 1024 loops?

Comment: Or handle the key input and port input in separate threads

Comment: Rather than trial and error from scratch, it seems better to modify based on this sample program. [bmo/mttty](https://github.com/bmo/mttty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code *only* reads a *single* byte on each iteration. This is *very* slow.

You're using an extra intermediate buffer (e.g. `single_val_buf`). Better/easier to read directly into the `m_buf` target buffer (i.e. no need to copy the bytes).

The code also polls the keyboard on every iteration. The important part is to keep up with the data and excessive keyboard polling can slow things down. Better to poll the keyboard periodically (e.g. every so many iterations).

*Side note:* `goto` is ugly/bad style and is easily refactored.

---

Here's some refactored code. It is annotated

I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

Anyway, here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SUCCESS 0
#define BUF_SIZE 2048

char *hComm_init_error_modes[7] = {
    "", // NOT INTENDED FOR USE
    "", // NOT INTENDED FOR USE
    "ERROR OPENING SERIAL PORT\n",
    "ERROR RETRIEVING COMM STATE\n",
    "ERROR CONFIGURING COMM STATE\n",
    "ERROR RETRIEVING COMM TIMEOUTS\n",
    "ERROR CONFIGURING COMM TIMEOUTS\n",
};

HANDLE hComm;

uint8_t m_buf[BUF_SIZE];
// NOTE/BUG: not needed -- we can read directly into m_buf
#if 0
uint8_t single_val_buf[1];
#endif

//int m_buf_full = 0;

int
hComm_init(char *port)
{

    hComm = CreateFileA(port,           // PORT NAME
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,   // READ/WRITE
        0,                              // NO SHARING
        NULL,                           // NO SECURITY
        OPEN_EXISTING,                  // OPEN EXISTING PORT ONLY
        0,                              // NON OVERLAPPED I/O
        NULL);                          // NULL FOR COMM DEVICES

    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return 2;
    }

    DCB commStateConfig;

    if (!GetCommState(hComm, &commStateConfig)) {
        return 3;
    }

    commStateConfig.BaudRate = 921600;
    commStateConfig.ByteSize = 8;

    if (!SetCommState(hComm, &commStateConfig)) {
        return 4;
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS comm_timeouts;

    if (!GetCommTimeouts(hComm, &comm_timeouts)) {
        return 5;
    }

    comm_timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
    comm_timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    comm_timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
    comm_timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    comm_timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;

    if (!SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &comm_timeouts)) {
        return 6;
    }

    return 0;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("\nWrong number of inputs!"
            " Please provide the com port number and nothing else.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char portname[11 + strlen(argv[1])];

    strcpy(portname, "\\\\.\\COM");
    strcat(portname, argv[1]);

    int err = hComm_init(portname);

    if (err != SUCCESS) {
        printf("%s", hComm_init_error_modes[err]);
        goto RUNTIME_ERROR;
    }

    printf("OPENED AND CONFIGURED SERIAL PORT SUCCESSFULLY\n");

    if (!SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR)) {
        printf("SetCommMask failed with error code: %ld\n", GetLastError());
        goto RUNTIME_ERROR;
    }

    DWORD dwEvtMask;
    DWORD read;
    int readcount = 0;

#if 1
    int ret = 0;
    unsigned int iter = 0;
#endif

    while (1) {
        ++iter;
        read = 0;
        dwEvtMask = 0;

        // Check for key press
        if (((iter % 1024) == 1) && kbhit()) {
            // ESC pressed
            if (27 == getch()) {
                printf("Key ESC pressed, exiting...\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwEvtMask, NULL)) {
            if (dwEvtMask & EV_ERR) {
                printf("Wait failed with error %ld.\n", GetLastError());
                ret = -1;
                break;
            }

// NOTE/BUG: this only reads _one_ char at a time and uses an extra buffer
#if 0
            if (dwEvtMask & EV_RXCHAR) {
                if (!ReadFile(hComm, single_val_buf, 1, &read, NULL)) {
                    printf("\n\nERROR when reading\n\n");
                }
                m_buf[readcount] = *single_val_buf;
                readcount++;
            }
#else
// NOTE/FIX: read many bytes at once -- put them directly into the final buffer
            if (dwEvtMask & EV_RXCHAR) {
                if (! ReadFile(hComm,
                    &m_buf[readcount], sizeof(m_buf) - readcount,
                    &read, NULL)) {
                    printf("\n\nERROR when reading\n\n");
                    ret = -2;
                    break;
                }

                // increase total accumulated count
                readcount += read;

                // a nicety: force immediate repoll of keyboard
                iter = 0;
            }
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: better to use ">=" rather than "=="
#if 0
            if (readcount == BUF_SIZE) {
#else
            if (readcount >= BUF_SIZE) {
#endif
                double diff_ms = (clock() - start) * 1000. / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

                print_m_buf();          // for testing only, remove later
                printf("Time spent reading: %f ms\n", diff_ms);
                break;
            }
        }

        // handle WaitCommEvent error?
        else {
            DWORD dwRet = GetLastError();
            if (ERROR_IO_PENDING == dwRet) {
                printf("I/O is pending...\n");
                // To do.
            }
            else {
// NOTE: no need to call GetLastError twice
#if 0
                printf("Wait failed with error %ld.\n", GetLastError());
#else
                printf("Wait failed with error %ld.\n", dwRet);
#endif
            }
        }
    }

    if (ret < 0)
        printf("Runtime error, program exited.\n");
    CloseHandle(hComm);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thnk you very much! This worked like a charm :D

Comment: You know, I'm surprised a modern PC can't read a serial port at 1 byte per system call  at 96kbps.

Comment: @Joshua If I'm reading the question correctly, the baud rate is 921600, which is ~92,000 bytes/second (i.e. 10x faster). So, that would be 92,000 syscalls. That means each syscall has to execute in 10.8 us or less. And, a number of those syscalls will come up with 0, so the strain would be even greater. So, it would appear that syscall overhead is more than 10.8 us [under windows]. Plus, a keyboard check might involve a round trip message over USB to poll it, so it may be the reduction in `kbhit` calls.

Comment: @CraigEstey: Keyboard checks don't round-trip to the keyboard, and baud is about the same as bits (not bytes) per second.

Comment: @Joshua I'm well aware that baud is bits for serial/UART. But, I think you should reread my comment [and yours]. You said: "96kbps" or 96 kilobits / second. OP's rate is 10x higher than that: 921600 baud --> 921,600 bits / second --> 92160 bytes / second

Comment: @CraigEstey: lol I see it now. I abbreviated kilobytes per second as kbps.